# Creating a controller/service to persist data, with information from the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

In angular I have in a view a list of items which will be display in another view depending on whether they are checked or not.

this is the view where you check which sports you want to display in the another view

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sports"
          ng-init="sport.checked = true"
          ng-click="sport.checked = !sport.checked">
    {{:: sport.name}}
</ion-item>
```

this is the another view

```
<div ng-show="sport.checked"
  ng-repeat="sport in sports">
    {{sport.name}}
</div>
```

as you see all those sports has an `ng-init = sport.checked = true`, so all the sports are shown at the beginning but you can unchecked those sports in order to don't see them until you checked it again.

that's all I have so far and works, but once you refresh the page, all the checks and unchecks die, everything restarts after refreshing, so as you know I need to persist that data in a DB or something, I am using node.js/sails.js along with Redis for this. I have an idea of how to create almost everything in the node.js part, but I need some help in the Angular part with the controller and the service, so I need your help here.

I want that the users are able to checked their sports only once, and not every time they log in on the app.

So what functions can I add to the controller to advise to the service when a sport has been unchecked, and how the service will be receiving that data ?

also, if you have any suggestions for the NodeJS part, that would be awesome too.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to use sessionStorage/localStorage, or if you're feeling really bold dive into the exciting world of indexeddb. However, these things aren't so much angular as they are straight up javascript. You'd need to hook them up to a service probably.

Comment: yes bro, but read the question, I mean, I know what I have to do, what I need to do first, is send that info to an Angular controller, and then to an Angular service, that is what I need to know first, after that I can start working on the NODEJS part @S.Buda

Comment: You shouldn't need to send the data to an angular controller, it looks like it should already be in a controller- wherever your sports object is held. From that you can just create a service and inject it into your controller. Then you can handle the data as needed.
That being said, I don't see what you need the NodeJS for in this regards, as that strikes me as information you'd want as part of your client session, not some server state. There again, I've used node very little, so it could be I don't understand that aspect of things.

Comment: I have users in my app that they will want to log out, and log in again and see their sports checked and unchecked, it is not something that you want to do every time you log in, I want that the users are able to checked their sports only once, and not every time they log in on the app. @S.Buda and how can I do that you said? I am an angular novice

Comment: I see. so you'd be saving that information as part of your user profile in some server db. I was invisioning that would be data you would store in the browser with localstorage or indexeddb. My statement still stands though. Inject a service into your controller and then have the logic in your service to do what you need with it (be it posting it to your server or saving it locally)- e.g. `angular.module("whatever").controller("controller", function(myDataService){`

Comment: If need be, set a watch on your sports array and whenever it changes invoke your service.

Comment: I have that part created, what I say, is that I need something like:     ```$scope.sportsChecked = function() { $scope.sport = sport.checked = true }``` and ```$scope.sportsUnchecked = function() { $scope.sport = sport.checked = false }``` @S.Buda that is the kind of help I need and how I call that functions from the DOM

Comment: I guess I'd really need to see more of your controller code to understand what you're having difficulties with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could use. This is very bareboned. All the `$http` fucntions work with promises. The controller will get the settings from the service when, if that is empty it requests new settings from the service

```
angular.module('app').controller('appctrl',['appsrv','$scope',function(appsrv, $scope){
    $scope.settings = service.settings;
    if(!$scop.settings){
       //retrieve data from server when it's not in the service
       appsrv.getSettingsRemote().then($scope.settings = service.settings);
}

    }]).service('appsrv',[$http, function($http){

    return {
    getSettings :  function (){
    // get settings from localstorage
},
    setSettings :  function (){
    // store settings to localstorage
},
    getSettingsRemote : function () {

    $http.get('url').then(//set things locally);
}
}

}]);
```

Then from your view you could just assign the controller to the view and then reference to your settings like `{{settings.propname}}`

I don't want to write all your code  but maybe this has given you insight in what you could do

Comment: and which function do I need to put in the controller in order to catch when a sport has been checked or not ?, I thought in something like  ```function() { $scope.sport = sport.checked = true }```, or how ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer That should happen automatically with the angular databinding. You're essentially doing that in your ng-click on that ion-item that you have.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Unless you mean so that you can run some function when that value changes, in which case you'd need a `$scope.$watch("sport.checked",function(oldVal,newVal){/*Do something*/})`

Comment: Or you could create a method for it when you calll `ng-click="setSport(true)"` and in your controller have `$scope.setSport = function(var setting){$scope.sport.checked = setting}`. This is all very basic stuff that is handled in the angularjs tutorial

Comment: @VeldMuijz that's what I mentioned, perfect. just something else, why ```(var setting)``` as a params ?

Comment: You could do several things. You could just pass in the function that you want in the ng-click definition i just wanted to show you the way you could pass parameters from your view to the controller.